# How to make code that changes status using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want some code that switches the status from Playing <help to Playing {number of servers} servers every 30 mins using `task.loop()`

current code:

```
Stat = True

@tasks.loop(minutes=30)
async def change_status():
    new_status = "<help" if Stat else f"{len(client.guilds)} servers"
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(new_status))
    Stat = not Stat
```

error: Stat is not defined

I  need code that uses `client.guild` not `bot.guild` please

Comment: and i think u have to use global keyword on Stat variable i guess, and also, did u define ur Bot as client or bot? (i mean, whats the variable name for ur Bot object?)

Comment: i defined it as client

Comment: did u made the Stat variable as global inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the `Stat` variable global otherwise it won't work. You also can't use `Stat = not Stat`. Use `Stat = None` instead. If you want your status to change every 30 minutes you have to change the `Stat` variable every 30 minutes to True, None, and so on. But in your code, you're changing it to `None` every time.

```py
Stat = True

@tasks.loop(minutes=30)
async def change_status():
    global Stat
    if Stat:
        new_status = "<help"
        Stat = None
    else:
        new_status = f"{len(client.guilds)} servers"
        Stat = True
    
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(new_status))
```

---

I'm not sure how you are starting your task, but if you get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'change_presence'`, then start your task in the `on_ready` event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
```

Comment: Did it work for you?